# How to remove space rows and columns in table in html

Tags: html, html-table

In my html page,  I have one table, for every row there are two buttons, I want to display them without any space between rows and columns, i.e., no space between columns in each row and no space between two rows in table. How can I get this? I tried with:

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td colspan = 2><a data-role="button" href = "getFun()" >check</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>                               
          <td><a data-role = "button"   href = "getFun()">check</a></td>                               
          <td><a data-role = "button"  href = "getFun()">check</a> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td><a data-role = "button" href = "getFun()">check</a></td>
          <td><a data-role = "button" href = "getFun()">check</a></td>
     </tr>
 </table>

table{
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

But its not working for me. Please tell me the solution. I edited my code. Please find it

Comment: Question is not clear, give me a correct picture of your problem

Comment: Which browser **and** version do you use ? Do you have any stylesheet included before your actual html table ? If you can, use a tool like 'Firebug' to check all styles actually applied to your table.

Comment: I'm using Safari browser. I included style sheet also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/5rkpy/